# List names of files/directories with paths relative to current directory

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, directory

My problem statement itself is pretty much clear to what I need to do actually.

For now this is working for the files in current directory I am in.

```
for /r %%F in (*) do call set files=%%files%% "%%F"
echo %files% >> ..\..\TargetFolder\a\targetfile.config
```

But I want to move up two folders & then dig inside one folder & there are multiple folders. I want the name of all those folders.

For example just like this:

```
for /r %%F in (..\..\TargetFolder\) do call set files=%%files%% "%%F"
echo %files% >> ..\..\TargetFolder\a\targetfile.config
```

It would be a great help for me if you could tell me if I can keep them in an array, or print them one by one in a for loop and do some other operations in each iteration too.

Comment: Try `for /R "..\.." %%F in (*) do` or `for /R "..\..\TargetFolder" %%F in (*) do`...

Comment: Thankyou @aschipfl,
Worked like a charm, only thing is, i wanted folders/directories , so i replaced (*) with (/) . it filtered out the directories.

Comment: To list directories do `for /D /R` instead of `for /R`...

Comment: @aschipfl this was cool. also could you please suggest me, how can i get the last directory name in the path separately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way. I am glad you already have a solution. I would worry about putting all directory names in one variable as it might become too long. If there are many, I would process them individually as below, or write the list to a file for later processing.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%d IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path '..\..' -Directory | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }"') DO (
    SET "THEDIR=%%~d"
    ECHO Do something with "!THEDIR!"
)
```

If you want to maximize cryptic notation and reduce comprehension, aliases and minimum parameter names can be used.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%d IN ('powershell -nop "ls -Path '..\..' -dir | %%{$_.fullname}"') DO (
    SET "THEDIR=%%~d"
    ECHO Do something with "!THEDIR!"
)
```

Comment: I am getting one issue with file path.

I am storing one path ../../TargetFolder in a variable name targetFolder

set targetFolder = ../../TargetFolder

but when i am trying to read value from this, 

%targetFolder%  

the for loop doesn't find path and just exits, but when i enter the full path ../../targetFolder, 

it just works fine. 
lit , @aschipfl

Answer (score 0):

Alright, to specify an (absolute or relative) root directory other than the current one for `for /R`, do this, for example:

```cmd
for /R "..\..\TargetFolder" %%F in (*) do echo %%~F
```

To get a list of directories rather than files, add the `/D` option:

```cmd
for /D /R "..\..\TargetFolder" %%F in (*) do echo %%~F
```

To get the pure file/directory names, use `%%~nxF` instead of `%%~F`.

---

To get files located in the immediate children of the root directory, do this:

```cmd
for /D %%D in ("..\..\TargetFolder\*") do for %%F in ("%%~D\*") do echo %%~F
```

To get directories located there, do this:

```cmd
for /D %%D in ("..\..\TargetFolder\*") do for /D %%F in ("%%~D\*") do echo %%~F
```

Comment: @GuramritSingh - `%%~nxF` is explained near the end of the help output of the FOR command. `FOR /?`

Comment: aschipfl & @lit 
Is there any way to look into just the immediate children of directory and not the sub-children of the first child folders

Comment: Perhaps this: `for /D %%~F in ("..\..\TargetFolder\*") do echo %%~nxF`?